# why do i keep getting 400 response using facebook graph api

Tags: java

i tried to change the facebook api graph into string using following method and it gives me (400 response) all the time the link i'm tring to use is `"https://graph.facebook.com/search?type=adinterest&q=[\""+type+"\"]&limit=10000&locale=en_US&access_token="+token` the error that i keep getting is after the code because it's too long

```
public String reader(String link) throws IOException {
    URL url = new URL(link);
    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
    conn.setRequestProperty("accept-language", "en-US,en;q=0.9");
    conn.setRequestProperty("user-agent", "MyJavaApp");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(conn.getInputStream());
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    while(sc.hasNext()) {
        sb.append(sc.next());
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

`java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: https://graph.facebook.com/search?type=adinterest&q=["faegew"]&limit=10000&locale=en_US&access_token=gwge at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1985) at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1577) at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:224) at java.base/java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1192) at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.libs.org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(IOUtils.java:1153) at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.libs.org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(IOUtils.java:1174) at FacebookAPI.<init>(FacebookAPI.java:19) at MainFrame.actionPerformed(MainFrame.java:80) at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1972) at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2313) at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405) at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262) at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279) at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6617) at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3342) at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6382) at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2264) at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4993) at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2322) at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4825) at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4934) at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4563) at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4504) at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2308) at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2773) at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4825) at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772) at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721) at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715) at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391) at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85) at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95) at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745) at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743) at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391) at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85) at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742) at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203) at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124) at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113) at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109) at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101) at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps:

```
import org.json.*;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.apache.commons.io.*;


public class url2json {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException, MalformedURLException, IOException {
        JSONObject myJson = new JSONObject(IOUtils.toString(new URL("http://ip.jsontest.com"), "UTF-8"));
        System.out.println(myJson.get("ip"));
    }
}
```

Comment: tysm, i tested ur code and it worked perfectly, but when i putted the api that i want to use it gave same problem (400 response) so ig it's the api i want to work with is the problem, the link i'm trying to work with is `"https://graph.facebook.com/search?type=adinterest&q=[\""+type+"\"]&limit=10000&locale=en_US&access_token="+token`